# solr does not index all the documents

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, dbpedia

I am getting some set of records from dbpedia, for 1-365 all days. Indexing these unique records to solr. In each iteration nearly 2000 documents getting indexed

Total number of records I sent to solr are `449872` and  total documents on solr are `"numFound": 428411`

I set `maxDocs` limit to 100000

is there any idea for this?

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs?

Comment: Possible reasons 1. Did you commit after your process finished (which solr version are you using? ). if not then try /update?commit=true, and then check numFound 2. Are you using a "id" field in your schema which is the "uniqueKey" also? If yes, then can u check if all your documents have  unique ids. If any docs have same id, they will be overwritten by the new one. 3. As TMBT said, check the solr log files for errors. To enable detailed logging for indexing, check if this is true in your solrconfig file - <infoStream file="${solr.core.name}.txt">true</infoStream>

Comment: @jay: yes `commit=true` is there, and I have `link` as unique key, and I am indexing unique records only. Log does not display any error. Is there any log file where it display all previous log records? I check log file in example folder, but not error there

Comment: What is the fieldType for "link" field?  Also did you try enabling the infostream and check for errors in it after indexing?